# Ubuntu Lamp accessing mysql from outside

Tags: mysql, lamp

I installed this LAMP: https://github.com/teddysun/lamp

Everything is perfectly setup, I still have to access mysql from outside, I was expecting to find the usual `bind-address` in mysql config file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

In looking inside the `/etc/my.cnf` I cannot find any `bind-address` variable.

I've checked as well into `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` `/usr/etc/my.cnf` `~/.my.cnf` but the are all not-existent file.

**Edit**

This is the full config:

```
[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
port                           = 3306
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /tmp/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql.pid
skip-name-resolve
skip-external-locking

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M

# INNODB #
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 64M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 2
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 256M

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 0
query-cache-size               = 0
max-connections                = 256
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 1024
table-open-cache               = 400


# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /usr/local/mysql/data

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /usr/local/mysql/data/mysql-error.log
```

Is there a specific/different setup for this LAMP script?

Comment: Can you post the content of `my.cnf`? Are there any other included config files?

Comment: @Khaled tks - see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When not specifically defined the [`bind-address`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) defaults to `*`

> If the address is **`*`**, the server accepts TCP/IP connections on all server host IPv6 and IPv4 interfaces if the server host supports IPv6, or accepts TCP/IP connections on all IPv4 addresses otherwise. Use this address to permit both IPv4 and IPv6 connections on all server interfaces. This value is the default.

Comment: Tks, just to make sure I've made myself clear, the `bind-address` var is not present, and I still cannot access from outside: `Access denied for user '.....'@'IP' (using password: YES) (1045)` - even if by default should be `*` as my IP should fall under the `anything (*)`

Comment: @Mr.Web To access a database via the network, you not only have to set the bind-address (or leave it at the default), but also explicitly allow access per database (table). Read the docs how to do that. "Access denied" points to the later, not the former.

Comment: @gf_ Tks! It was a GRANT problem :)